# Replacing Data that contain certain character in R

Tags: r, replace, conditional-operator

If i have the following data frame,
[image]

How can i replace data that contain "not detectable" to "NA" effectively?
The dataset is much bigger and the only commonality is the "Not detectable" as condition
I tried using gsub but it just return the data as T or F so i don't know what to do with it.

Comment: `df$somevariablename[grepl("Not detectable", df$somevariablename)] <- NA` or perhaps `df$somevariablename <- replace(df$somevariablename, grepl("Not detectable", df$somevariablename), NA)`?

Comment: It seems you do not take time to appreciate the solutions given in your previous posts. You do not even comment on them. At least you should get to thank someone who answers your post correctly by even upvoting or accepting their solution if it solves your problem.